# How can I forward from a port based on source IP?

Tags: networking, server, iptables, ufw

I have two syslog sources that come in on port 514 and I want to forward them to two different ports based on source IP (for a graylog server).

I'm able to forward everything on that port to another local port.

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 514 -j REDIRECT --to-port 1514
COMMIT
```

But if i try to filter based on source ip nothing seems to happen, it just all continues going to port 1514.

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -p udp -s $some_ip --dport 514 -j REDIRECT --to-port 1513
-A PREROUTING -p udp -s $some_ip --dport 514 -j REDIRECT --to-port 1514
COMMIT
```

Any help would be gladly appreciated, as I'm sure I must missing something massively obvious.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are putting the rule in the right table and chain. I was fighting with this same scenario yesterday with iptables. Try doing a packet capture to make sure packets are coming in as you believe they are with tcpdump "tcpdump -s0 -w  port 514". You can also set up iptables logging of packets to verify what chain amd take things are flowing through. Inspect current rules and command line iptables arguments with "iptables -nL" and "iptables -S"

https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Netfilter-packet-flow.svg

Comment: I prefer `sudo iptables -v -x -n -L` so as to also get the packet counters, which I find useful for debugging.